# What Are The Exact Differences Between The US Judicial System And The Proposed Israeli Judicial Reform, In Terms Of Checks And Balances

Tags: united-states, law, supreme-court, israel, comparative-politics

The Israeli Judicial Reform plan is still in the making, so changes to the precise rules of the proposal are expected. But the basic ideas of it are as follows:

1. According to the current law, some sitting justices can veto new appointments to the Supreme Court. The new law will enable the political majority to appoint new justices against the will of the sitting justices.
2. The Supreme Court will be unable to cancel Basic (or 'constitutional') laws.
3. The power of the Supreme Court to cancel simple laws will be restrained (exact terms still in the making).
4. Currently, Ministers cannot choose legal advisers, and their advice is considered binding. The new law will enable ministers to hire and fire advisers as they please, and they can choose not to listen to them.
5. Currently, the Cabinet's legal adviser is also the Attorney General (combined with No. 4, this makes the AG the stongest unelected official in the government). The new law wants to divide that position.
6. If the Supreme Court cancels a law, the parliament can vote to reinstate the law.

I hope to add refrences shortly.

Comment: It seems like there are a lot of differences based on what you have provided.

Comment: @JoeW, "In terms of checks and balances". Is the US government more restrained today, than the Israeli government would be after implementing the judicial reform? How exactly?

Comment: At a quick glance items 2, 3, 6 would not fly in the US as the court can rule on any law passed and it can't be reinstated just by voting on it again.

Comment: It may be difficult to answer this because many of the US checks and balances are not explicit in the Constitution or law but a result of tradition. The most obvious one is the principle of judicial review.

Comment: With or without the Israeli judicial reform the two legal systems are still completely different and built on different legal traditions. So why do you want to compare the US to Israel? Why not, say, Japan to Israel? Wouldn't a better comparison be Israel with and without the reform? I can try and write an answer if you first explain what you are looking for.

Comment: Why just the US? Some of these seemed to be inspired by the indian constitution or based to prevent a hijacking of powers that some in India claim the indian judiciary has done.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist, The Biden Admin seems to be somewhat concerned with the new judicial reform, which gives the acting government "too" much power. So I'm interested to know, if Biden himself has less power now than the Israeli PM would have after passing the reform.

Comment: "ministers cannot choose legal advisers, and their advice is considered binding": does this mean that ministers are required to have legal advisors without being able to choose them?  If so, who does choose them?  Is the advisors' advice merely "considered binding" or is it actually binding?  If merely "considered," by whom, or because of what custom?

Comment: @phoog, Minister's Legal advisers are hired by various committees of non-elected officials, for a set amount of years - so even as new governments are formed the old legal advisers remain. The court has a custom of not accepting the representation of any minister besides the acting legal adviser - so if someone charges a minister in court, the only one who can represent him is the legal adviser who thinks that the minister is acting against the law...

Answer (score 5):

Can tell at a glance that something like 6 only happens in some other countries [not the US], but in Canada or the UK, IIRC. Since details on #3 are still pending can't say much about that, but it's also a [roughly] feature in some other systems, e.g. French, IIRC. Overall, it appears that the Israeli executive/PM is cherry picking the most favorable features (favorable to executive/parliamentary power) from all those foreign examples. So the whole package is a substantial weakening of the power of the judiciary in constitutional matters as well as the way it is appointed (the current system seems more similar to what some Europeans do in the latter regards--that issue has also been contested over there.) And if "cherry picking" isn't derogatory enough, others have [coined](https://academic.oup.com/book/38889/chapter-abstract/338035059) the term "frankenstate" for the result of such practices.

Also, as suggested in some comments, purely on paper the US system is even more unbalanced than in historical reality. There's little [but self-restrain/tradition] that prevents a political/Congress majority there from packing the Supreme Court with new members and overturning [constitutionality] decisions that way.

---

It's also difficult to make a apples-to-apples comparison with the US for some other, less direct reasons including the fact that Israel's constitution is just a collection of Basic Laws that can be passed by simple majority in the Knesset, so formal constitutional amendments are much easier to make than in the US.

Somewhat more subtly but discussed in [this colloquium](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kwmr9QXs9g) (for instance), the power of party discipline (in the legislature) also has an effect on the judiciary in systems where on paper it is easy to mess with it from the legislative side. The US is rather famous for the *lack* of party discipline (and/or laws to enforce it), which in a sense has prevented [ruling] party leaders from pushing the right buttons to rule by decree (typically done [elsewhere] in this order: using party discipline to enforce their vision on the party and then using the latter to overrule any judiciary objections through parliament--either directly or through personnel changes). OTOH Israel has more features of party discipline, like closed PR list elections and an anti-defection law on the books, although the latter has been rather ineffective [in practice](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/1354068819836037). (Yeah, informal methods of party discipline/control have also emerged in the US, in the form of endorsements.)

Comment: The U.S. has something similar to Number 6 in that there is nothing preventing Congress from passing a new law that is modified to better handle the parts that are unconstitutional.  Additionally, SCOTUS can render only parts of a law unconstitutional, such that the law is still a law, but the unconstitutional portions are null and void for the enforcement.

Comment: Re #6 in the UK: Acts of Parliament cannot be struck down by a court in the way that Acts of Congress can be; but if a court _interprets_ the law in a way that Parliament doesn't like, Parliament can amend the law to "correct" that interpretation ([example](https://www.landlordzone.co.uk/information/tenancy-deposits-superstrike-and-the-deregulation-act/)).

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff: thanks, I knew it was somewhat more complicated, but could not remember the details.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff "if a court interprets the law in a way that Parliament doesn't like, Parliament can amend the law to "correct" that interpretation": the same is true in the US and indeed in any jurisdiction (substituting: "congress" or "the legislature" for "parliament," of course).

Answer (score 3):

> According to the current law, some sitting justices can veto new
> appointments to the Supreme Court. The new law will enable the
> political majority to appoint new justices against the will of the
> sitting justices.

This moves closer to the U.S. status quo (one that is not widely considered to be a good one internationally or among many domestic commentators).

But there are many countries (Poland is one example which I am certain that this has been the case at least until very recently) where appointments to higher judicial offices must be made from the ranks of experienced judges in lower judicial offices, often by internal judicial branch administrators to some extent.

Also, the U.S. has a federal system, and in that system, the vast majority of civil ands criminal litigation is handled by state court systems over which the federal government has no control except through appeals from state supreme courts to the U.S. Supreme Court with 50 states plus highest courts in D.C., Puerto Rico, U.S. territories, and the military justice system all handled by just nine U.S. Supreme Court justices who hear less than 100 cases a year.

Importantly and somewhat relatedly, in the U.S., election administration is mostly a state function with only limited federal law and federal court involvement, so Congress and the President don't have direct control over the institutions that hold the elections for those offices in the way that the Israeli legislature does.

So, control over the Israeli Supreme Court is a much more complete centralization of judicial authority than it would be in the U.S. legal system.

> The Supreme Court will be unable to cancel Basic (or 'constitutional')
> laws.
>
> If the Supreme Court cancels a law, the parliament can vote to
> reinstate the law.

The highest court can't cancel basic law in most countries. Some notable exceptions are the U.K. (because it doesn't have an entrenched basic law), India (in which the Supreme Court has held that some higher principles can trump the constitution), and many Islamic countries (in which Islamic law can override the secular constitution).

This is not allowed in the U.S. federal government where it is very hard to amend the U.S. constitution.

It is allowed in Canada in most but not all circumstances (under "the notwithstanding clause") and in the U.K. under the structure of its "constitution."

Also, keep in mind that in many countries (including the U.K.), personal liberties are entrenched primarily through international, multilateral treaties, which effectively allows basic protections of individual liberties of the kind found in the U.S. Bill of Rights to be abrogated prospectively by withdrawing from the treaty in question, which is nearly equivalent to this situation.

Israel happens to protects individuals mostly through its constitution rather than through multilateral treaties.

Israel is [close to the U.K. model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Laws_of_Israel):

> The Knesset enjoys *de jure* parliamentary supremacy and can pass any
> law by a simple majority, even one that might arguably conflict with a
> Basic Laws of Israel, unless the basic law has specific conditions for
> its modification. Basic laws that include specific conditions include
> the following:
>
> Article 4 of the Basic Law of the Knesset, on the electoral system,
> can be amended only by a majority of 61 of the 120 Knesset members.
>
> Article 44, which prevents the amendment of the law by an Emergency
> Regulation, can be amended only by a majority of 80 members. A
> majority of the Knesset members can amend the Basic Laws on the
> government and on freedom of occupation.

So, the ability of parliament to reinstate a provision declared to be invalid isn't a huge change from the status quo in Israel.

Further, it is worth noting that in the U.S. and in many other countries, it is fairly easy to change the constitution with a vote of the legislature and a referendum. And, if a proposal to change the constitution has wide support in the legislature, a referendum to adopt that change is also likely to win that referendum.

The answer from Fizz is also correct in noting that:

> purely on paper the US system is even more unbalanced than in
> historical reality. There's little [but self-restrain/tradition] that
> prevents a political/Congress majority there from packing the Supreme
> Court with new members and overturning [constitutionality] decisions
> that way.

This has indeed been done several times in U.S. history, and the mere threat that it could be done was one of the main ways that President FDR in U.S. history managed to cause the Lochner era Supreme Court to moderate its decision making.

> The power of the Supreme Court to cancel simple laws will be
> restrained (exact terms still in the making).

This proposal is too vague to say much about.

Many countries do not allow their primary supreme court to cancel simple laws, reserving that power to a special constitutional court. But, Israel does not have a separate constitutional court, so its Supreme Court serves as both an ordinary Supreme Court and as a constitutional court.

The U.S. does not do this, however, and instead affords the power to cancel unconstitutional ordinary laws to all judges (not just the U.S. Supreme Court).

> Currently, Ministers cannot choose legal advisers, and their advice is
> considered binding. The new law will enable ministers to hire and fire
> advisers as they please, and they can choose not
> to listen to them.
>
> Currently, the Cabinet's legal adviser is also the Attorney General
> (combined with No. 4, this makes the AG the stongest unelected
> official in the government). The new law wants to divide that
> position.

In the U.S. federal government, legal advisors for the executive branch are chosen by the head of government (who is also the head of state) for the entire executive branch (i.e. unified), rather than on a department by department basis.

In almost all state governments in the United States, legal advisors for the executive branch (i.e. the Attorneys-General) are unified and separately elected and do not work at the pleasure of the Governor and other executive branch officers.

In the Israeli context, which has a unicameral parliamentary system and a weak President, in which the President and the judiciary are pretty much the only officials formally independent of the Prime Minister, this is a pretty significant change in a way that it would not be in the U.S. or many other countries.

Comment: "This is now allowed in the U.S. federal government". Do you mean "not"?

Comment: @Fizz Yup. A typo. Thanks. Fixed.